# How to change different values within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

For each brand there are different categories. I need to have a button that shows different brands. And if I click that brand for instance bmw I get 4 different categories displayed in a line graph. x-axis is date and y-axis is price and color of lines is displayed by category within that brand.
This is dataframe. These are just 5 of many values

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00')},
 'price': {0: 281435.0, 1: 102577.0, 2: 204844.0, 3: 271199.0, 4: 144790.0},
 'Brand': {0: 'bmw', 1: 'ford', 2: 'hyundai', 3: 'mercedes-benz', 4: 'nissan'},
 'category': {0: 'bmw_5 series_executive_2016',
  1: 'ford_focus_trend x_2015',
  2: 'hyundai_tucson_elite plus_2017',
  3: 'mercedes-benz_e-class_edition e_2015',
  4: 'nissan_qashqai_black edition_2014'}}
```

Comment: Do you want to make a dash app?

Comment: @rpanai yea.....

Comment: you have received an answer and if you found it useful yourself, please consider awarding upvote or accept the answer. If it doesn't work, please leave comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# imports

from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash 
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# app
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

server = app.server

brands = df['Brand'].unique()  ## get unique brands for dropdown

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='filter-brands',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in brands],
            value='bmw'
        ), 
         style={'display': 'inline-block',
                'width': "100%",
                'borderBottom': 'thin lightgrey solid',
                'backgroundColor': 'rgb(250, 250, 250)',
                'padding': '10px 5px'}),
    html.Div(dcc.Graph(
            id='categories-timeseries'
        ))
])

# to create timeseries chart on update
def create_time_series(dff):
    return px.line(dff, x="Date", y="price", color='category')


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('categories-timeseries', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('filter-brands', 'value'))
def update_timeseries(brand):
    dff = df[df['Brand'] == brand].sort_values("Date")
    return create_time_series(dff)


app.run_server(mode="jupyterlab")
```

or use

```
app.run_server() ## to open in browser
```

[image]